# Bus Error in OS X x86_64 in Execve call

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, execve

I am trying to mimic Security Tubes execve tutorial (http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/demystifying-execve-shellcode-stack.html) in 64bit Asm.  I am not sure where the bus error is coming from.  I stepped through through the app in GDB but the error didn't occur until after I was out of frame.  If anyone knows what is happening, I would love to hear from you.

```
.section __DATA,__data
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _start
_start:
    xor %rax, %rax
    push %rax
    movabsq $0x68732f6e69622f2f, %rdi
    push %rax
    mov %rsp, %rsi
    push %rdi
    mov %rsp, %rdx
    mov $0x2000059, %rax
    syscall
```

Comment: For one thing, `push` is 64 bit in 64 bit mode, with a 32 bit sign extended immediate. So you actually end up with `2f 2f 62 69 00 00 00 00 6e 2f 73 68 00 00 00 00` on the stack. Instead, you could try `movabsq $0x68732f6e69622f2f, %rax; push %rax`

Comment: Thanks @Jester. Still getting the bus error though. Will update my code to reflect your instruction.

Comment: You loaded `rdi` but pushed `rax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work better but I don't have osx to test:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    xor %edx, %edx                    ; NULL for env
    movabsq $0x0068732f6e69622f, %rax ; /bin/sh<0>
    push %rax
    mov %rsp, %rdi                    ; filename
    push %rdx                         ; NULL for argv terminator
    push %rdi                         ; argv[0] = filename
    mov %rsp, %rsi                    ; argv
    mov $0x200003b, %eax              ; I think 59 is decimal
    syscall
```

Comment: I was playing around with the code to narrow down the pieces I was doing wrong.  I noticed that you `push %rdx` (line 7).  What is the purpose of that push?  I noticed the bus error comes back if I comment that out.

Comment: @JLegendre : because `sys_execve` requires argv[] and/or envp[] to be null terminated arrays of character pointers. Without the NULL pointer termination the kernel doesn't know where the end of the array is. The length of the arrays is not passed as parameters so the NuLL terminator is a way to identify the end of the array(s) while processing. It is similar in nature to why an array of characters is ended with a NUL(0) character - so that the end of the string can be found without being told the actual length ahead of time

Comment: @MichaelPetch Fantastic explanation! Thank you!